# Facebook custom audience PHP users replace

Tags: php, laravel, facebook, facebook-sdk-4.0, facebook-custom-audience

I'm trying to sync a [custom audience](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/audiences/guides/custom-audiences) with the [php fb sdk](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/3.2.3/). My script looks like this:

```
foreach ($users->pluck('email') as $email) {
    $hashed[] = [hash('sha256', $email)];
}
    
try {
    (new CustomAudience('custom-audience-id'))
      ->createUsersReplace([], [
          'payload' => [
              'schema' => [
                  'EMAIL',
              ],
              'data' => $hashed,
          ],
          'session' => [
              'session_id' => rand(1, 10000000),
              'batch_seq' => 1,
              'last_batch_flag' => true,
              'estimated_num_total' => count($hashed),
          ],
      ]);
} catch (Exception $ex) {
    $this->info($ex->getMessage());
}
```

The script runs successfully, when I look into the history tab FB is telling me the x records have been replaced successfully:

[image]

However, the size is not updated (after processing for a couple of hours):

[image]

When I upload the records manually through an excel sheet the size is updated correctly. Obviously, something is wrong with my PHP script but can't figure out what's wrong.

Comment: if you only update email try pass `schema` as string and hash data as one-dimensional array: `'schema' => "EMAIL"` and `$hashed[] = hash('sha256', $email);`

Comment: Thanks but that's not working. `(#2650) Failed to update the custom audience: This audience was created from data source FILE_IMPORTED.MULTI_HASHES, which does not support data source FILE_IMPORTED.HASHES_OR_USER_IDS.` @ChinhNguyen

Comment: What is Type of Custom Audience? Is it CUSTOM?

Comment: Yes it's custom @MHIdea

Comment: @Jamie change $hashed data to 1-D array as Chinh Nguyen mentioned and with that also change `'data' => [$hashed]` to make it 2-D array and check working or not

Comment: When I do that I keep getting `(#2650) Failed to update the custom audience: This audience was created from data source FILE_IMPORTED.MULTI_HASHES, which does not support data source FILE_IMPORTED.HASHES_OR_USER_IDS.` @Haridarshan

Comment: What is the output of this `curl -G \
-d 'access_token=<AccessToken>' \
https://graph.facebook.com/v11.0/<CustomAudienceID>\?fields\=data_source | jq`

Comment: Also, what is the response of `createUsersReplace`?

Comment: @Haridarshan when I change everything back too what I had the response is a `FacebookAds\Object\CustomAudience` object so that's good. But the message smaller then 1000 keeps showing up in my fb business manager. So basically the audience is useless. When I execute the command you've given I get `Could not resolve host`. Seriously FB api is terrible :)

Comment: count of `$hashed` records and excel sheet rows are same or different?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to add custom audience to your audience set for digital marketing. The thing is Facebook ads take 24 hours before reflecting the scripting results. As your initial audience set was less then 1000 it will take 24 hours to update the target audience. So wait for that time duration and then check for other options. Also cross check with pixel official code if they have updated anything.